# Avocado tree looking poorly

Tags: avocado

I have sprouted and grown an avocado tree (for fun, not profit) from a seed I kept about three years ago. The tree. Has just started growing well again after winter, so its alive.

However, it just looks really bad, as if its dehydrated. I water it every time its leaves start to hang, and it has worked so far. I have also put it in a larger pot. Note that the top leaves look normal. Those have recently grown.

The first three years it was in my porch and had ample indirect sunlight. Now, since I moved, it has ample direct sunlight behind a window.

I read I should wait with planting it outside until the stem is brown. At the time of writing its still green.

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong?

[image][image]